# How do I check the prometheus version?

Tags: find

I'm running two servers with Ubuntu and one of them has grafana and prometheus running on it. I'm trying to rebuild the same environment on the other server however I fail to find the version of it. Searching with `find / prometheus*` also didn't have any result.

What should I do?

Comment: `find / -iname '*prometheus*'` would be more like it

Comment: Many thanks @muru. with your command I find it at /opt/prometheus/, and have version info (0.20.0) inside.

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to find the version from within prometheus (or grafana or similar) you can query the metric: `prometheus_build_info`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As suggested, with the command `find / -iname '*prometheus*'`, the result included among other things:

```
/opt/prometheus/prometheus-0.20.0.linux-amd64
/opt/prometheus/prometheus-0.20.0.linux-amd64/prometheus.yml
/opt/prometheus/prometheus-0.20.0.linux-amd64/prometheus
```

Which shows the version is 0.20.0.
Thanks a lot for the help.

Also, you can use `./prometheus -version` in the folder to find the detail of the version:

```
prometheus, version 0.20.0 (branch: master, revision: aeab25c)
  build user:       root@77050118f904
  build date:       20160616-08:38:14
  go version:       go1.6.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it has changed in the last few years but I had to use two hyphens before version:

```
./prometheus --version
```

not

```
./prometheus -version
```

Comment: I'm using version 2.26.0 and the prometheus executable is located at `/bin/prometheus`

Comment: using 2.11.1, had to use `--version` as well.